# bionic 18.04 avahi not playing on a mac network

Tags: 18.04, avahi

I am running 18.04. I am on a network running a variety of systems but the philosophy is very apple. They are using Bonjour for discovery. This is not working on my box. If I ping a .local name I get "name or service not known". if I used avahi-browse -arl it just sits there and doesn't list anything.

I have looked at nsswitch.conf and tried various combinations of msdn and have removed the return on fail clause.

My adapter is a bridged tap interface to support kvm vm instances. Watching with Wireshark, on the ping, I can see mdns sending 3 qm questions for that address. I don't see a specific response. I can see other devices on the network talking mdns multicast.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this further. I am guessing that the multicasts from my box are not getting across the bridge to the wire but am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu includes the Avahi service, which uses the .local domain as a multicast DNS zone. For example, if you have an Ubuntu system named “ubuntu” on your network, it can be accessed at the address “ubuntu.local”. To do this, Avahi automatically takes over all DNS requests ending with ".local" and prevents them from resolving normally. If you are on a network with existing DNS addresses that end with .local, such as a Windows Small Business Server network, you’ll have to change Avahi’s domain from .local to a different domain before .local addresses will resolve normally.

1. Launch a terminal window by clicking the “Terminal” shortcut in your applications menu. On Ubuntu’s default desktop, click the “Dash Home” icon at the top left corner of the screen, type “Terminal” and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Type the following text into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   `sudo nano /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`
3. Input your password at the password prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Scroll down using your arrow keys and locate the `#domain-name=.local` line under `[server]`.
5. Remove the “#” symbol and change “local” to “alocal” so that the line reads:

   `domain-name=.alocal`
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save Avahi’s configuration file in Nano.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit Nano. Addresses ending with .local will now resolve correctly.

Comment: Thankyou but no that is not the problem. There is no dns based local domain. I can see the multicasts going out on the wire requesting resolution. I can see the responses coming back but Avahi doesn't seem to get them or do anything with them - no Avahi logging of the answers even when run in the foreground and and highest level of logging. Again thanks for the answer.